# Onboard graphics not working

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, gpu, integrated-graphics

I had recently some problems with my GPU, so I decided go back to my dedicated graphic card, Intel HD. I did set the BIOS options to use `Onboard Graphic` and `Use always onboard graphics even if graphic card slot is used`. After restart monitor says "No signal" video. The GPU is still connected to the slot.
So how can I solve this problem?

Specs:
MOBO: `Gigabyte h61m-d2h-usb3`
CPU:  `i5-2320`

Comment: Is the monitor connected to integrated GPU's outputs?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, it is connected to the monitor with HDMI, but I did set bios options to use onboard graphics. Should I remove GPU? I remember in the past I used that HDMI input with integrated graphics.

Comment: But _which_ HDMI? If you were using dedicated GPU up to this point, then the monitor was most likely connected to dedicated GPU's output. Integrated GPU can't use these ports, it has its own outputs on motherboard's back panel. Have you plugged the monitor to motherboard's outputs?

Comment: Oh, maybe is it connected to HDMI gpu output. I must see if there is HDMI output of motherboard. I dont know why but I was thinking I had only 1 HDMI, I will take a look this afternoon. Thanks in advance, I will comment again when I check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using dedicated GPU up to this point, then the monitor was most likely connected to dedicated GPU's output. Integrated GPU can't use these ports, it has its own outputs on motherboard's back panel. Plug the monitor to motherboard's output.